# Select next 24 hours for every record in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, time, group-by

My Table looks like this:

```
| Attackerip | timestamp |
```

Now I want to check how many attempts per 24 hours from the first attempt each IP has made. I want to have all results with less than 5 attempts in this timespan.

For example: Attacker **A** has attacked at 23.05.2016 03:00PM, now the query should select the next 24 hours starting from that attempt and check if **A** has tried more than 5 times in this period. If **A** has indeed done this I want to return the Ip of **A**, the timespan(if that is possible) and the number of attempts.

```
SELECT table1.attackerip, table1.stamp::date, count(*) 
FROM thesislog_v2 table1 INNER JOIN thesislog_v2 table2 
ON table1.attackerip = table2.attackerip AND table2.stamp <= table1.stamp 
AND table2.stamp >= table1.stamp -  interval '24 hours' 
GROUP BY table1.stamp::date, table1.attackerip HAVING COUNT(*) <=5       
ORDER BY table1.attackerip asc
```

I am not sure whether this query does what I think it does though, because I do not know how GROUP BY with a condition works. I think it also includes Results where an attackerip has 5 attempts on this day and not only in the 24 hour span.

Additionally it would be great if there was a possibility to exclude all records where the timespan between the last attempt and the next attempt is less than 24 hour. But I do not think that this is even possible. For example in a 24 hours timespan someone has 5 total attempts. After the last attempt in that timespan another attempt is immediately started. My current query would include this result, which it should not.

**Edit** with sample Data (*I hope this is enough, otherwise I can upload some sample Data*):

```
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 10:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 11:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 12:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 13:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 10:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 11:36:55.294747" |
```

Should return:

```
183.3.202.190" | 5 
183.3.202.191  | 3
```

because it is less than 5 attempts in a 24 hour window starting from the first attempt

```
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 10:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 11:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 12:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 13:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 13:36:55.294747" |
```

Should return NULL because it is more than 5 attempts in a 24 hour window starting from the first attempt

Comment: what is the exact version of Postgres that you're using?

Comment: I am running 9.4.5

Comment: could you please provide sample data ? and an expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 select attackerip,stamp_init,count(*) attack_count from (
   select a.attackerip,stamp,min(stamp_init) stamp_init,min(stamp_24) stamp_24 from thesislog_v2 a
join (
  select attackerip,stamp stamp_init,stamp+'24 hours'::interval stamp_24 from thesislog_v2
   ) b on (a.attackerip=b.attackerip and a.stamp between b.stamp_init and b.stamp_24) 
  group by 1,2
) c group by 1,2
having count(*) <=5
```

On your first sample data the result is the same as what you expect
On the second that return 5 attacks because you have two row with the same attackerip/stamp (Is it normal ?) , if you add one millisecond at the last timestamp , the query find 6 rows and return null like it's expected. 
And if you add one line to your first sample like  this :

```
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 10:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 11:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 12:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.190" | "2016-05-07 13:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 10:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-07 11:36:55.294747" |
|"183.3.202.191" | "2016-05-08 11:37:55.294747" |
```

The result is :

```
 183.3.202.191  2016-05-08 11:37:55.294747  1
 183.3.202.190  2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747  5
 183.3.202.191  2016-05-07 09:36:55.294747  3
```

Is it what you want ?

Comment: Sounds exactly like what I want. Will test it and then mark your answer. Thank you!